# How to search LIKE string value in multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, multiple-columns, sql-like

I've read multiple solutions to find if one value is in multiple columns, but I want to see if the (string) value is like the value in one or more columns.

So basically said can I do a LIKE OR on multiple columns in one elegant statement?

A better way to do this:

```
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE col0 LIKE '%value%' OR col1 LIKE '%value%' OR col2 LIKE '%value%' OR ...;
```

And this then for the rest 10 or so columns.

KR

Comment: Thanks @ErgestBasha, I guess this might work. Will try asap!

Comment: @ErgestBasha: I've tried it but that doesn't return any value. If I just use the like on one column where I know a result should be found it finds it with no problem. But not with the concat option.

Comment: It is a very simple table with 10 columns. The first one is an ID and the rest are string(50) fields. (Data is poured in from one dirty source and at regular intervals I try to clean-up this table to insert clean data in another table.)

I found a solution that works, but is requires me to create the sql statement with a bit of python code. This does exactly what I want but I guess that there is a more elegant solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This (python) bit gives me the results I want.

```
    columns = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7", "col8"]
    sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE col0 LIKE '%"+_name+"%'"
    for column in columns:
        sql += "OR "+column+" LIKE '%"+_name+"%s'"
    sql += ";"
```

There must be a better way but this works for now.